# Examples of storing not so critical complex data structure in app engine Memcache (java) for inter-session interactions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, data-structures, memcached

Not-so-critical data can be stored in memcache. However, how can complicated data be stored there while being updated simultaneously by different user sessions.

Say a graph, tree or linked list? It is OK to miss a node, but it is bad to loose the whole graph/tree/list if a node is evicted. An example here is sending user update notification among online-users.

App engine's appstats use a predetermined 1000 bucket which is good ( I think there is no dependency among them). But I am thinking about more complicated cases...

Any tutorial, example or theory would be considered helpful...

( Memcached tag was added, but I know it is not for app engine )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store more complex data, you need to serialize it before you place it into shared memory.

When you want to update this data, you will need to deserialize back into your complex structure, update the structure then serialize again to place the structure back into shared memory.

I am curious - why memcache? There are many other shared memory storage systems out there such as MemBase, Redis and Hazelcast, with Hazelcast adding some help to hide some of the complexity of storing some more complex structures (like lists and maps). Hazelcast also adds nice features like cluster wide locks and data listeners which can come in useful (full disclosure: I decided on Hazelcast).

Of course if you want to spend real money for licensing, you always have Terracotta which can completely abstract you from this complexity.

Comment: My bad. I was asking a data structure being access by sessions simultaneously. Like a multi-threaded data structure that you cannot lock the whole thing...  ( Because we can accept dropped update, like UDP ) I will check "MemBase, Redis and Hazelcast, with Hazelcast" to see if they can be ported to App Engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing a graph, and don't mind nodes going missing, just store each node under its own memcache key.

If all the data going away at once is "bad", though, you probably shouldn't be using memcache in the first place. Complete wipes are rare, but can happen.

Comment: What are the common algorithms to iterate the graph/list/tree nodes in this situation? There is nothing called root node....